# ASP.NET application synchronisation with microsoft outlook

Tags: asp.net, outlook

I have an invoice solution, programmed in asp.net c#, which is running on IIS onder a domain. 
In my application their is a part which displays the invoices and their status ( open, overdue, closed ).

Now I would like to synchronate this in my outlook so that when a new invoice is made in the application, for example invoice 00001, expire date 18/01/2014, this is visible in my outlook agenda.

How can this be done? I have searched for solutions but nothing fits. or am I missing something?

The application data is stored in a mysql database.

And what with other programs like iCal, ....

Comment: I have seen this post, but its not what I am looking for. Is their any solution that automatically syncs with an offline calendar. Something like exporting mysql entries in an xml file that can be read by a calendar?

Comment: Do you want to export in your web application the appointment so it can be added automatically to your outlook agenda?

Comment: I think something like when a new invoice is made, or edited, or changed from status, a new export with last changes should be done to a place where for example outlook or iCal automatically read this and put this in their calendar. But I am not shore of how calendars do this, this synchronisation.

Comment: There is a tool called Redemption that allows your to import appointment to outlook, you can investigate further here as I'm no expert in this topic: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeAppointmentItem.htm

Comment: Ok thanks in advance I will investigate this later on...